# Unable to popBack to expected fragment in android

Tags: android

I have problem with popBackStack in android. I have 3 MenuItem of Navigation Drawer FragA, FragB, FragC.My problem , when i click on FragA, then Click on FragB, Then Click on FragC my total fragment will count 3. I press back then, it will remove FragC and resume FragB.
I expect that when I press Back it will return to FragA. Here is my code below. Please kindly give me some solution. Thank in advance.

Code when i add fragment stack.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.home){
    fragment = new FirstFragment();
}
if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.setting){
    fragment = new SecondFragment();
}
if(menuItem.getItemId()==R.id.trash){
    fragment = new ThirdFragment();
}
this.replaceFragment2(fragment);
```

Method replace fragment

```
private void replaceFragment2(Fragment fragment){
    String backStatName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStatName,0);
    if(!fragmentPopped){ //if fragment not in backstack
        FragmentTransaction transaction =  manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.flContent,fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(backStatName);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **TRY THIS**

```
Fragment fragment = null;
if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.home){
    fragment = new FirstFragment();
}
if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.setting){
    fragment = new SecondFragment();
}
if(menuItem.getItemId()==R.id.trash){
    fragment = new ThirdFragment();
}


     if (frag != null) {

            openFragment(frag);
            dLayout.closeDrawers();
            dLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }




    public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //fragment not in back stack, create it.
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (!fragments.contains(backStateName)) {


        // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();

        fragments.add(backStateName);
        System.out.println("backStateName" + fragments);

    } else {
        // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out,R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

**ONCREATE**

```
 final android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
```

**onBackPressed**

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (dLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        dLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } 
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. let's me try.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

Replace your `FragA` with `FragB` like,

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragB()).disallowAddToBackStack();
```

**and add in your Actiivty**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me why disallowAddToBackStack()?